# Как поменять обводку выбранного элемента из QComboBox. Qt Designer StyleSheet

Tags: qt-designer, qss, qcombobox, qlistview, outline

Этот код меняет `background` объектов в `QComboBox` при наведении:

```
QComboBox QListView {
    selection-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
}
```

**test.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">

    /* вот этот код работает */


QComboBox QListView {
      background-color:rgb(52, 58, 64);
    selection-background-color:white;
    
 }
/* а вот этот нет  */
QComboBox QListView::item:hover{
border:1px;
border-color: rgb(170, 85, 127);

}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>250</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>69</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

а мне нужно поменять `border` объектов в `QComboBox`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я добавляю `StyleSheet` через *Qt Designer*. 
Не могу найти как поменять параметры `item` в `QComboBox`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Т.е. опубликуйте модуль `.ui` и лучше расскажите и покажите что вы хотите поменять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
QComboBox {
    font: 18pt Fira Sans Condensed;     
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    border-top: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-left: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-right: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3e3e3e;
    padding: 5%;
    max-height: 30px;
    min-width: 140px;
    color: white;
    selection-background-color: #5e5e5e;
}

QComboBox::drop-down {
    border: none;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(down-arrow.png);
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:pressed {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px; left: 1px;
}

QComboBox QListView {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    
/*  outline: 0;                    попробуйте так    */
    outline: 2px solid red;     /*    или так        */
    
    color: white;
    selection-background-color: #5e5e5e;
    padding: 5%;    
}
```

---

**q1408477_test.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>440</width>
    <height>448</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QWidget {
    background-color: #18465d;
}

QComboBox {
    font: 18pt Fira Sans Condensed;     
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    border-top: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-left: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-right: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3e3e3e;
    padding: 5%;
    max-height: 30px;
    min-width: 140px;
    color: white;
    selection-background-color: #5e5e5e;
}

QComboBox::drop-down {
    border: none;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(down-arrow.png);
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:pressed {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px; left: 1px;
}

QComboBox QListView {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    
/*  outline: 0;                    попробуйте так    */
    outline: 2px solid red;     /*    или так        */
    
    color: white;
    selection-background-color: #5e5e5e;
    padding: 5%;    
}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>70</y>
      <width>261</width>
      <height>42</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>New Item</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>440</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**down-arrow.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Михаил пожалуйста.